# test method fails with "Attempt to de-reference a null object" but code in class runs

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I am getting a strange error when running my test method:

```
@isTest
public class Batch_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status_TESTMETHOD{

public static testmethod void testBatch_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status(){
    //List<cif_entity__c> lstEntities = [Select Name, ID_CIF__c, CIF_id__c, Equation_Status__c from cif_entity__c where equation_status__c = :'Updating Equation']; 
    //system.debug('number before = ' + lstEntities.size());
    //System.assertEquals(1, lstEntities_Before.size(),'BEFORE = ' +  lstEntities_Before.size());  

    test.startTest();
    BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status myClass = new BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status();
    myClass.lnumber = 'No Limit';
    database.executebatch(myClass,1);

    test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The test fails every time with a message `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` and the stacktrace given is:

> Class.BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status.start: line 13, column 1

But I know that the code has run because I have received an email with the results in a csv file.

Here is the batch class I am testing which sends the email:

```
global class BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
private integer RecordNo = 0;
public string scope = '1';
public String lnumber = 'No Limit';
public string updatedEntities = '';
public string csvData = '';

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    system.debug('start');

    Bulk_Address_Switch__c bas = Bulk_Address_Switch__c.getInstance('isBulkUpdate');
    bas.Field_Value__c = 'Yes';
    update bas;

    RecordNo = 0;

    system.debug('set qry');//Updating Equation
    string query = 
        'Select Name, ID_CIF__c, CIF_id__c, Equation_Status__c from cif_entity__c where equation_status__c =\'Updating Equation\'';

    if(lnumber != 'No Limit')query += ' limit '+lnumber;

    system.debug('return QUERY STRING:');
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<cif_entity__c> scope) {

    system.debug('in execute');

    updatedEntities='';

    Datetime myDatetime = Datetime.now();
    String myDatetimeStr = myDatetime.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
    system.debug('date = ' + myDatetimeStr);   

    system.debug('start loop through scope');   

    for(cif_entity__c c:scope){
        system.debug('in loop through query, #' + RecordNo);
        updatedEntities += string.valueOf(c.Name)+',' +  string.valueOf(c.ID_CIF__c)+',' + myDatetimeStr + ',' +c.Equation_Status__c +',';
        c.Equation_Status__c = 'Equation Updated'; //
        updatedEntities += c.Equation_Status__c + '\n';
        system.debug('Entity record for: ' + c.Name);
        RecordNo++;
        update scope;
        csvData +=updatedEntities;
        system.debug('Update records record no: ' + RecordNo);
    }       
    system.debug( RecordNo + ' records updated!');
    system.debug(csvData);

}

/**
 * @description gets invoked when the batch job finishes. Place any clean up code in this method.
 * @param context contains the job ID
 */ 
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    //Set Is bulkUpdate to No
    system.debug('set Bulk_Address_Switch to No');
    Bulk_Address_Switch__c bas = Bulk_Address_Switch__c.getInstance('isBulkUpdate');
    bas.Field_Value__c = 'No';
    update bas;

    string csvHeader='Name, Cif ID, Last Modified Date, old Equation Status, new Equation Status\n';
    csvData = csvHeader + csvData;

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

    //Create csv attachment     
    blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvData); //updatedEntities
    string csvname= 'UpdatedEntityrecords.csv';
    csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
    csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);

    //Create Email      
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'TeamEmail@ACompany.co.uk'}; 
    String[] ccAddresses = new list<string> {'AnIndividual@ACompany.co.uk'};

    email.setSenderDisplayName('Entity records Equation status Batch job');
    email.setSubject('Entity records Equation status updated');       

    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    email.setCcAddresses( ccAddresses );

    email.setPlainTextBody('Please see the attached file');
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});

    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }
}
```

it essentially finds all the records in our custom object that have a certain status set in a field, and updates them...

So what am I doing wrong in my test method, I cannot even begin to look for code overage until it even works...

Comment: Are you creating any data in your test?

Comment: @Girbot: well, no - there is already data in there, so I am just running the batch to do the update... then calling `System.assetEquals` to check the results...do I need to create a basic record as part of my test, then call the method on that?

Comment: Yes you need to create the data you need in a test method/class. I didn't even look at the batch class because I couldn't see any data setup in the test method.

Comment: @Girbot: thanks, should I put the code to create the record after the `test.startTest()` or before?

Comment: Before then your SOQL query limit will be refreshed by using test.startTest()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of bare bones answer which I will add more detail to when I can, but **it doesn't look like you are creating any data in your test class.**

Create all the data you need before calling `test.startTest()` - including any custom setting records you need. I can see one in there:

```
Bulk_Address_Switch__c setting = new Bulk_Address_Switch__c(Name='isBulkUpdate')
upsert setting;
```

With regards to `test.startTest()`, from the [Dev Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_startTest):

> Each test method is allowed to call this method only once. All of the
>   code before this method should be used to initialize variables,
>   populate data structures, and so on, allowing you to set up everything
>   you need to run your test. Any code that executes after the call to
>   startTest and before stopTest is assigned a new set of governor
>   limits.

Comment: Hey @Girbot, nice answer. It seemed like there were a couple missing words I added in, and just fleshed out the custom setting detail a bit. Hope you don't mind, seemed better than adding an answer just to get that detail in there. +1, and awesome avatar.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not at all, I appreciate it. It was my intention to come back to it as I added it in a rush :)